# Column population and auto_increment

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one of suppliers and another of products

I want the ID of each product to contain 6 digits,
plus
That the ID of each product will start with the ID digits of its supplier,
And that the last digits will be auto_increment with zeros appearing in between
For example:

supplier that his ID is 158
The ID of each product that belongs to this supplier will read as follows:

158000001,
158000002,
158000003
And so on

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Is MyISAM engine safe for you? or you need in transactional engine? *I have two tables one of suppliers and another of products* Provide CREATE TABLE of both tables, include only main columns (id, ref_id, name) and FK definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use StoredProcedure for this. You can use LPAD function for that. Suppose if you use LAPD(17,3,0) & LAPD(6,3,0), IT WILL RETURN 017 & 006 simultaneously. I would prefer StoredProcedure for this because, you have separate tables. If not, Trigger is more suitable.

You can check https://database.guide/how-to-add-leading-zeros-to-a-number-in-mysql/ for this

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS  `SpProductID` ;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SpProductID`(
    V_SUP_ID    CHAR(3)
    )
BEGIN

# call SpProductID('158');

DECLARE V_PROD_NO   INT;
DECLARE V_PROD_ID   CHAR(9);

SELECT  IFNULL(MAX(CAST(RIGHT(PRODUCT_ID,6) AS INT)),0)+1
FROM    PRODUCT
WHERE   LEFT(SUP_ID,3)=V_SUP_ID INTO    V_PROD_NO;

SET V_PROD_ID=CONCAT(V_SUP_ID,LPAD(V_PROD_NO,6,0));

#   now insert it in product table


    END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When supplier id is 158 & product_no is 1, then product_id will be 158000001.

Comment: I'm new to SQL so the answer is a little hard for me to understand.
I use
Workbench,
Is the syntax the same as your answer? Because this is the first time I have encountered such a syntax.
Plus what is it
StoredProcedure

Comment: In the meantime, I managed to create the following:

INSERT into Products (id)
VALUES (concat (158, LPAD (7,5,0)))

What gives me
ID: 15800007

But I still can't get her last digit to be AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: This is not just sql syntax. It is stored procedure. It is pre-compiled. It takes less time than ordinary syntax. It recides in server. When you create this, you will see that this is created into your DB's StoredProcedure setion. This code was tested by me & it works without any error.

Comment: concat (158, LPAD (7,5,0))) this code will not increment. You have to increment last 6 part like this way concat (158, LPAD ("Max Number +1",6,0))).

Comment: I tried what she wrote down here it still does not work